# Android Kotlin - How to pass a named function to DialogInterface.OnClickListener parameter in another function?

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, onclicklistener, function-parameter

This is my function declaration,

```
fun MyDialog(ctx: Context, msg: String, yestext: String = "", OnYes: DialogInterface.OnClickListener? = null): AlertDialog

fun MyClickListener(){}
```

How do i pass MyClickListener into MyDialog?

MyDialog(context, "Delete data", "Yes", MyClickListener) showed type mismatch.

In DialogInterface.class

```
  public interface OnClickListener {
    void onClick(DialogInterface var1, int var2);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an implementation of the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` in order to pass it to it.

Like:

```kotlin
class MyClickListener : DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(var1: DialogInterface, var2: Int) {/* Code */}
}

// then call the constructor.
MyDialog(ctx, "", "", MyClickListener())
```

But indeed this isn't the cleanest way further. Just like java you can do SAM conversions in **Kotlin 1.4**.

```kotlin
// inline implementation of DialogInterface.OnClickListener using SAM conversion
MyDialog(ctx, "", "") {/* Code */}
```

And if you want to, you can extract the SAM conversion into a function that suits your usecase.

```kotlin
fun MyClickListener() =
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener { /* Code */ }

//Now call like this
MyDialog(ctx, "", "", MyClickListener())
```

Comment: Implementing class MyClickListener work well, the other method has error though. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Eddi do you have Kotlin 1.4, configured in your project? SAM Conversion is only available on that, https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/03/kotlin-1-4-m1-released/

Comment: Oh I just check mine is 1.3. Thanks for clarify.